# Is it possible to have multiple 'request:URLRequest' variables

Tags: php, flash, urlloader

I'm creating a flash game that imports data from a PHP database and was wondering if this is something that can be done with multiple urls?

For example, if I am pulling data from 'http://exampleurl.php' would it be possible to pull data from another url 'http://exampleurltwo.php"' at the same time using something similar to...

```
var request:URLRequest= new URLRequest("http://exampleurl.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(request);
```

The two php forms I'm using are quite different and I am not able to combine the two, so any advice on how I could achieve the results I'm after would be greatly appreciated!

Obviously can't create another variable or I get a conflict definition, was wondering if I could create an instance of it though?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the variable 'request2'. So I had one variable 'request' and another that did the same thing called 'request'. At the time of posting I had already tried this and it didn't work so sorry to waste your time!